# Referencing lines whose styles are set using \pgfplotsset

Tags: pgfplots, cross-referencing

In the MWE example below, it seems that the line style for the reference is not set correctly (in the plot, the circles are not filled, but they are filled when referencing them).

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug? If so, is there a workaround? Other than setting the style manually for all the lines in my document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.append style={thick, black},
  every axis plot post/.append style={
    every mark/.append style={mark size=3,solid,fill opacity=0}
  }
}

\begin{document}
Why is this marker \ref{myline} different but this one
\ref{myline-correct} is correct?

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[mark=*]
    table [x=x, y=y]{%
      x y
      0 0
      1 1
      2 2
      3 3
      4 4
    };
    \label{myline}

    \addplot[mark=square, mark size=3,solid,fill opacity=0]
    table [x=x, y=y]{%
      x y
      4 0
      3 1
      2 2
      1 3
      0 4
    };
    \label{myline-correct}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is because you use `post`.  If you remove this, it works fine.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks! Sorry, I am a total newbie when it comes to pgfplot.

Comment: I think this is a useful question (+1) which others also may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See section 4.7.1 of the pgfplots manual, where it says that "The every axis plot post style can be used to overwrite parts (or all) of the drawing styles which are assigned for plots.". See also section 4.5.12, where the sequence is detailed. So the bottom-line is that if you drop the `post` directive,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.append style={thick, black},
  every axis plot/.append style={
    every mark/.append style={mark size=3,solid,fill opacity=0}
  }
}

\begin{document}
Now both the marker \ref{myline} and \ref{myline-correct} are correct?

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[mark=*]
    table [x=x, y=y]{%
      x y
      0 0
      1 1
      2 2
      3 3
      4 4
    };
    \label{myline}

    \addplot[mark=square, mark size=3,solid,fill opacity=0]
    table [x=x, y=y]{%
      x y
      4 0
      3 1
      2 2
      1 3
      0 4
    };
    \label{myline-correct}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]